# How do I bind a ComboBox to a one column list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I've seen how to bind a `ComboBox` to a list that has columns like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entries}"
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
SelectedValuePath="Name"
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Entry}"
```

But If I have a plain list with lets say countries in an `ObservableCollection<string>`, how do I bind to this?

I can't use `DisplayMemberPath` since I have no ColumnNames and the same with `SelectedValuePath`.

Once I just created a class with column names and added rows into that and later binded to it, but that just seems so nuts :P
The problem I have is to get the selected value out with binding.
Filling the list seems to work with just using `ItemsSource`.

The answer should be done in XAML only, if possible.

:P:P:P
My bad :P I just use the 'SelectedValue' and that has the value :D

Comment: It would be worth answering this yourself so people know you've found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad :P
I just use the 'SelectedValue' and that has the value :D